# Django query to return percentage of a users with a post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Two models Users (built-in) and Posts:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='user_post')
    post = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to have an API endpoint that returns the percentage of users that have posted.  Basically I want SUM(unique users who have posted) / total_users

I have been trying to play around with annotate and aggregate, but I am getting the sum of posts for each users, or the sum of users per post (which is one...).  How can I get the sum of posts returned with unique users, divide that by user.count and return?

I feel like I am missing something silly but my brain has gone to mush staring at this.

```
class PostParticipationAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
            
    def get_queryset(self):
        start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
        end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
        # How can I take something like this, divide it by User.objects.all().count() * 100, and assign it to something to return as the queryset?
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(post_date__gte=start_date, post_date__lte=end_date).distinct('user').count()         
        return queryset
```

My goal is to end up with the endpoint like:

> {
> total_participation: 97.3
> }

Thanks for any guidance.

BCBB

---

**EDIT**

OK, I am still struggling a bit.  I tried to create a serializer that just had a decimal field for participation_percentage like:

```
percentage_participation = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, max_value=100, min_value=0)
```

Then I calculate in the view, but I get an error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `percentage_participation` on serializer `ParticipationSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'percentage_participation'.

Error was the same if I made it a CharField (in case there was some string coercion?).

So then I tried to move it to a Serializer Method and put all the calculation logic in there.  This calculated fine, but if I had to provide a query_set in the view.  If provided a model object, it just returned the percentage as many times as the query (say Posts.objects.all() had a total of 100 posts, it returned the percentage 100 times).

So then I tried to override the get_queryset in the view, but I HAVE to return something.  If I just return { "meh", "hello" } then I return the percentage from the SerializerMethodField one time and the end result is exactly what I want.

I just have no idea as to WHY or how to do this correctly.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT #2**

OK so I realized why I was only getting one, it was iterating over the string I returned, which was one character.  When I returned "meh" it gave me three of the percentage, iterating over each character in the string...

I am not understanding from playing around, reading the docs, or using GoogleFu how to do this properly.  I just want to be able to perform some kind of summary logic on records from the DB - how can I do this properly?!?!

Thank you for all your time.

BCBB

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
# get total user count
total_users = User.objects.count()
# get unique set of users with post
total_users_who_posted = Post.objects.filter(...).distinct("user").count()
# calculate_percentage
percentage = { 
    "total_participation": (total_users_who_posted*100)/ total_users
}
# take caution of divion by zero
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Do I need to do this in the serializer?  Or the view?  How do I return it in the view if it's not a queryset?  Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: you have to create a new serializer which only have `total_participation` as a field. make this serilailzer for the view and still u can use it inside the get queryset method. or in the view. both are totaly okay

Comment: Thanks for your help, please see my edit above.  I have the result I want but I cannot be doing it correctly and don't really understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use djangos orm to do this completely but you can use the orm to get the user counts (with posts and total):

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, Count, When, Value

counts = (User
          .objects
          .annotate(posted=Case(When(user_post__isnull=False,
                                     then=Value(True)),
                                default=Value(False), 
                                output_field=BooleanField()))
          .values('posted')
          .aggregate(posted_users=Count('pk', filter=Q(posted=True)),
                     total_users=Count('pk', filter=Q(posted__isnull=False)))

# This will result in a dict containing the following:
# counts = {'posted_users': ...,
#           'total_users': ....}
```